# OCaml: Pattern matching vs If/else statements

Tags: functional-programming, if-statement, pattern-matching, ocaml

So, I'm totally new to OCaml and am moving pretty slowly in getting my first functions implemented.  One thing I'm having trouble understanding is when to use pattern matching abilities like

```
let foo = 
[] -> true
| _  -> false;;
```

vs using the if else structure like

```
let foo a = 
if a = [] then true else false;;
```

When should I use each?

Comment: The accepted answer below seems good in most cases. However, like in most (all?) programming languages, it's rarely a good idea to say something along the lines of `if condition then true else false`; you can instead just use `condition`. In this case, you can say `let foo a = (a = [])` and avoid both pattern matching and if statements.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think there's a clear cut answer to that question. First, the obvious case of pattern matching is when you need destructing, e.g.:

```
let rec sum = function
    | [] -> 0
    | head :: tail -> head + sum tail;;
```

Another obvious case is when you're defining a recursive function, pattern matching make the edge condition clearer, e.g.:

```
let rec factorial = function
    | 0 -> 1
    | n -> n * factorial(n - 1);;
```

instead of:

```
let rec factorial = function n -> 
  if n = 0 then 
    1 
  else
    n * factorial(n-1);;
```

That might not be a great example, just use your imagination to figure out more complex edge conditions! ;-)

In term of regular (say C like) languages, I could say that you should use pattern matching instead of `switch`/`case` and `if` in place of the ternary operator. For everything else it's kind of a grey zone but pattern matching is usually preferred in the ML family of languages.

Comment: +1. I'd augment this with one more rule of thumb.  If you're pattern-matching against `true` and `false`, consider an `if`. If your `if` uses a function to express a clear pattern-match, consider `match`. Plus `match` can avoid function calls, unlike many `if` expressions.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the signifincant difference is that the expression at the guards in the match statement is a [*pattern*](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~tews/htmlman-3.10/expr.html#htoc66) which means you can do things that allow you to break apart the shape (destruct) the matched expression, as Nicolas showed in his answer. The other implication of this is that code like this:

```
  let s = 1 in
  let x = 2 in 
  match s with
    x -> Printf.printf "x does not equal s!!\n" x
  | _ -> Printf.printf "x = %d\n" x;
```

won't do what you expect. This is because `x` in the match statement does not refer to the `x` in the let statement above it but it's a name of the pattern. In cases like these you'd need to use `if` statements.

Comment: I hate to dispense a downvote on SO, but this is actually incorrect — any destructuring in a `let` will behave exactly the same as that same destructuring in a `match` clause. `let (hd :: _) = [1; 2; 3]`. (In fact, IIRC, `let`-assignment actually desugars *to* a pattern-match.)

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE I think the example I wrote is bad. I meant that something like: `match s with x -> ....` is not the same as `if s = x then `. The `x` in the match statement is always going to pattern match with `s`. The `x` in the `if` statement is testing for equality.

Answer (score 1):

For me if..then..else is equivalent to match .. with | true -> .. | false -> .., but there's a syntax sugar if you are facing cases with nested pattern matching, using if..else in an interlace way can help you avoiding to use begin...end to separate different level of patterns

```
match .. with
| true -> 
    if .. then 
      match .. with
      | true -> ..
      | false -> ..
    else
      ...
| false -> ...
```

is more compact than

```
match .. with
| true ->
   begin 
    match .. with
    | true -> 
       begin
         match .. with
         | true -> ..
         | false -> ..
       end
    | false -> 
      ...
   end
| false -> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching allows for deconstruction of compound data types, and in general, the ability to match pattern within a given data structure, rather than using conditionals like the if.. then structure.  Pattern matching can also be used for boolean equality cases using the |x when (r == n) type construct. I should also add pattern matching is a lot more efficient than if... then.. constructs, so use it liberally!

Comment: FWIW, I don't think `match x with 3 -> f x | _ -> g x` is going to be any more efficient than `if x = 3 then f x else g x`. I would personally concentrate on clarity of the code.

Comment: In that case, I would agree.  But consider the case, 
    `match x with | 0 -> 1 | 1 -> 2 | 2 -> 3 | _ -> x + 1`  vs `if x = 0 then 1 else if x = 1 then 2 else if x = 2 then 3  else x + 1`.   If you were to benchmark these functions, the pattern matching would be significantly more efficient.  As the cases increase (especially when accelerated with recursion), the performance differences can increase by orders of magnitude.