# How to write `result?1:0` in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

in `java` we can write `result?1:0`. It is a short way to get a value depending on the `result bool`.

How can I write such a thing in OCaml?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536633/ocaml-pattern-matching-vs-if-else-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like this is a duplicate question. However, note that everything in OCaml is an expression. So the answer is `if result then 1 else 0`. You may need to parenthesize this depending on the context. (In the C family, a form I sometimes use for your expression is `!!result`.)